# Trouble saving data written to a file when I kill the app

Tags: c++, file

My program is always writing data to a file but when I close it before the program fully stops, the end result is nothing being written to the file. I would really like to be able to close it without completing it fully, so how can I fix this to make it constantly saving the file?

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("text.txt", std::ios::app);
bool done = false;
int info;
  while (done == false){
    cin>>info;
    outfile<<info;
    cout<<info<<"Choose different info";
       if(info == 100){
         done = true;
       }
  }
outfile.close();
```

This is obviously just an example, but it is very similar to my actual code.

Edit: When i say closing I mean killing it (Hitting red X at top right of console)

Comment: Sounds like you want to [flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) the data to the file semi-regularly.

Comment: "... but it is very similar to my actual code".  Please post actual code.

Comment: the code is too long

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  When you close what?  If you close the file, no further attempt to write to the file will work.  If you close the program: what do you mean by that?  If you mean that you are closing a window in which the program is running, we'll need more details with regards to the system and the type of window: the correct solution is to recover an event in this case and to shut the program down cleanly.

Comment: I might also add that you're using input without checking that the input succeeded.  This is an error, and can easily result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You likely need to [flush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/) your std::ofstream when you have done "enough" work.

"enough" work here is going to depend on your application.

Perhaps

```
...
outfile<<info;
outfile.flush();
...
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted to know! Thanks a lot

Comment: Fwiw, `std::ofstream` flushes on close (effectively invoking [`rdbuf()->close()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/close)). Either the OP isn't closing the file, or isn't opening it correctly.

Comment: I'm asking about when I close the file in the console using the x, not waiting for the program to finish and actually making it to outfile.close();

Comment: @bill that isn't closing the file; it sounds like you're killing the *app*. The condition you're describing is nowhere *near* reflective of the code you posted. That detail should be amplified in your question.

Answer (score 5):

The operation system doesn't write to the file when you call the write function to save time, it wait to check if you want to write anything else or for a time which will be "good" to write. You write to a buffer and the operating system will write this buffer to the file.
When you close the function it write anything that left in the buffer to the file. You can force your code to write to the file using flush method. Just flush your file after every time you write and you will be ok.
flush: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/flush/

```
outfile << n;
outfile.flush();
```

Comment: Just using `std::endl` might be all he needs.

Comment: He said that it write to the file only when the program finish completely. endl won't force it to write to the file. it will only make it look better to your eye.

Comment: @user2462683 Um. [**`std::endl`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) *will* flush a text-mode `std::ostream`. If you *don't* want that effect, write `'\n'` instead.

Comment: I checked it and you right, sorry for my comment. For this question, he didn't mention that he want to write in a new line so flush is the correct one. Although that he doesn't have endl so he won't be able to read his code.

Comment: @user2462683 I have a feeling he'll cross that bridge soon enough. =P

Comment: It isn't the operating system:  it is the c++ runtime library which avoids doing unnecessary buffer flushes because they are relatively expensive.